# Checking Apache on CentOS

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I am trying to run Apache on my CentOS.(I am having very basic knowledge on linux).

[[Apache Start Stop]](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-apache-startstop.html) using this link i tried to run: `apachect1 start`
But I got `-bash apachect1: command not found`

I also tried to check the status using `$ /etc/init.d/nginx status`
But I got `-bash: /etc/init.d/nginx: No such file or directory`

Then I tried to check if Apache is installed using : `which apache2`
But I got `/usr/bin/which: no apache2 in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/home/bebo/bin)`

It seems that Apache is not installed, however I can see httpd directory in etc folder. Does it have any significance?

Is my assumption correct, if yes how can I install/from where to download & install. Else correct where I am going wrong.

Comment: Typo : not `apachect1` but apachectL with a lowercase L at the end not the number 1

Comment: @Zimmi....it was the mistake using 1 instead l ....thanks I am able to run it....but different error now, I will check on it.

Answer (score 1):

These all the steps will be applied for CentOS 7 and CentOS 8

(**Note** also apply on RHEL 7/8)

I recommend running the below command to auto-remove the unused packages.

**Step 1:**

```
yum autoremove
```

**Step 2:** Now run the below command to update the CentOS

```
  yum update
```

**Step 3:** Installing the apache software package

```
yum install httpd
```

**Step 4:** Starting the apache service

The name of the Apache service is httpd. Use the below command to start and enable it at the same time in CentOS 7 or later version.

```
systemctl enable --now httpd
```

**Step 5:** Checking the httpd service status

```
systemctl status httpd
```

**Step 6:** Firewall configuration

As per now, we have to allow the HTTP service in the firewall. So, you can find the below command useful for that.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service http
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service https
```

Now reload the firewall service,

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

**Step 7:** Test the Apache server.
Put the IP address of your computer or the localhost on the web-browser; it will show you the Apache server is running.

To read more about Apache installation, you can visit my blog post. The blog post URL, you can find below.

[LAMP stack installation on CentOS/RHEL 7/8](https://www.linuxgurus.in/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-centos-rhel/)

[How to install the Apache web-server on CentOS 8](https://www.linuxgurus.in/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-8/)

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site in your post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: The disclosure doesn't need to be elaborate. Given that it's your site, disclosure can be as simple as "You can find a complete example on my blog: [link]". The main point is that people should know that the link is to something you're affiliated with (e.g. a blog you wrote) prior to clicking the link. However, keep in mind that the links need to be specifically relevant to the question/answer, not just something like "please visit my site [link to homepage]."

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to install apache on Centos is using the `yum` package manager.

Just run the following:

```
yum install httpd
```

After installation depending on your Centos version you start the Apache service  as follows:

**Centos 6**

```
service httpd start
```

**Centos 7**

```
systemctl start httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if apache is installed

> service httpd status

if the result is **"httpd: unrecognized service"**, it means not installed.

or

type your domain or ip in browser, if nothing to displayed, it means no apache installed.

*Install Apache*

> yum -y install httpd

*Start Apache service*

> service httpd start